# C++ chrono() function time difference is strange,considering that I'm working with different list sizes

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I need to deduce the time that different searches spend.I've been using different numbers,but the time doesn't change at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

bool MasCheckOne(int mas[], int k, int q) {
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
        if (mas[i] == k) {
            std::cout << "index: " << i << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool MasCheckTwo(int mas[], int k, int q) {
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
        if (mas[i] == k) {
            std::cout << "index: " << i << endl;;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool MasCheckThree(int mas[], int k, int q) {
    int i;
    int u;
    int l=0;
    u = q-1;
    int mid = (l + (u - l) / 2);
    while(l <= u) {
            std::cout << k << " ";
            i = (l + u) / 2;
            if (k > mas[i] ) {
                l = i + 1;
            }
            else if (k < mas[i]) {
                u = i - 1;
            }
            else if (mas[mid] == k) {
                std::cout << "index" << mid << endl;
                return true;
            }
            else if (k == mas[i]) {
                std::cout <<"index"<< l << endl;
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
//Mas generation in which outer file with a list of <q> size numbers goes
int *MasGeneration(string file_name,int q) { 
        std::ifstream ifs(file_name);
        int *arr=new int[q];

        for (int i = 0; !ifs.eof(); ++i)
        {
            ifs >> arr[i];
            //std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
        }
        return arr;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");

    int k; //The number that you search for
    int choice;
    int mas_choice;
    int q; //The number of element
    string file_name;

    cout << "Mas.txt for array of 3000 elements"<<" " << "Mas1000.txt for array of 1000 elements" <<" " << "Mas500.txt for array of 500 elements" << endl;
    std::cin >> file_name;
    cout << "Input the size " << endl;
    std::cin >> q;
    int* mas=MasGeneration(file_name, q);

    std::cout << " " << endl;
    std::cout << "What search?" << endl;
    std::cout << "1.Sequential search" << endl;
    std::cout << "2.Fast Sequential search" << endl;
    std::cout << "3.Binary search" << endl;
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::cout << "The number you look for" << endl;
    std::cin >> k;
    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    int* mas1 = new int[q+1];

    //serial search
    
    if(choice==1){
        if (MasCheckOne(mas, k, q)) {
        std::cout << "Success" << endl;
        }
        else {
        std::cout << "Failure" << endl;
        }
    }
    //fast serial search
    if(choice==2){

        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            mas1[i] = mas[i];
        }

        delete[] mas;
        mas = mas1;
        mas[q] = k;

        if (MasCheckTwo(mas, k, q))
            std::cout << "Success" << endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }
    //Binary search
    if (choice == 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (q-1); j++) {
                if (mas[j] > mas[j + 1]) {
                    int b = mas[j]; // created extra variable
                    mas[j] = mas[j + 1]; // change their places
                    mas[j + 1] = b; 
                }
            }
        }
        if (MasCheckThree(mas, k, q))
            std::cout << "Success" << endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }

        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto elapsed_ms = 
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin);
        std::cout << fixed << setprecision(10) << "время: " << elapsed_ms.count() << endl;;// к-во знаков после запятой
}
```

It is believed that Binary search should be faster when used with a large array size, but in my case it is almost 10 times slower than Sequential search (counting for 3000 elements).

Comment: Simplify the code, put separate functionality into separate functions. That makes it easier to test, debug and maintain. Not to mention that it's easier to test multiple times and not include things like output of other irrelevant things in your measurements (output to terminal is *slow*). And also remember to build with optimizations enabled.

Comment: And please note that your binary search case also does a *sort*, not only a search. That will of course add to the time. Especially since it's not the most effective sorting. For benchmarking and comparisons, it's always best to check not only the exact same data, but also have the data in the exact same order. So I suggest you do a `std::sort` call before any searching.

Comment: Another recommendation: Don't use your own explicit memory handling. Use vectors and all the standard algorithm functions you can. Oh, and 3000 elements is not that big. When you come to over a million it's beginning to be big. ;-)

Comment: 3000 is not large, it's 12kB. Your computer most certainly has more than 8GB of RAM. If you want large, try 1 billion elements.

Comment: You should remove `std::cout << ...` from the functions you are timing. Just performing console I/O will take longer than any searching you are doing. If you want to print results do it after the timing has been made.

Comment: A bubble sort followed by a binary search is definitely going to be slower than a linear search. Binary search is only faster on an already sorted list

Comment: "It is believed that Binary search should be faster when used with a large array size" says who? You confuse complexity with runtime